# How to upload and download files to the blockchain?

Tags: contract-design, blockchain, storage

I want to create smart contract which can upload and download file from blockchain. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Store data and retrieve it later? Download the whole blockchain in a contract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So files, in the traditional sense that I assume you are talking about when you use the word "files", are not stored on the blockchain; data is. All data is stored in HEX format and the more data there is, the more gas it needs to run. For this reason it's not really efficient or cost-effective to store "files" on the blockchain.

Instead, it's recommended to store files via IPFS or another decentralized / p2p / etc. system. If you want to learn more about referencing *data* stored in one contract from another contract, please check out the following:

[Interactions Between Contracts](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/interactions-between-contracts/)

and the followup question:

[How to reference coin contract already onchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/how-to-reference-coin-contract-already-onchain)

Comment: how can we do that using IPFS? @tayvano